# ng-model value is not accessed in the Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a mult-select on my page.
I am binding it with data in `PlanGroupData.EmploymentStatus.Ids.Id`, 
Now On click of save button, I want to get the selected value of multi-select.
but it is giving me empty array.

```
<multiselect ng-attr-name="GetStatus" ng-required="true" 
class="input-  xlarge" multiple="true" ng-model="EmpStatus" options="c._Value for c in PlanGroupData.EmploymentStatus.Ids.Id"></multiselect>
```

in the Controller,
I have declred

```
 $scope.EmpStatus =[];
```

and on button click , I am calling a function , and inside that function,

```
alert($scope.EmpStatus);
```

but it is an empty array.

Comment: What is "multiselect"?

Comment: its just like a  checkbox list control

Comment: There is no "multiselect" element in html. What kind of plugin module are you using?

Comment: Do you have the library that you used? Normally for a multi select you would use: `<select multiple="multiple">`